# Finding the sum of the first two rows VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying out a simple summation vba code. I want to find the sum of the first 2 rows in a defined range. However, I get a #VALUE error return upon running the following code:

```
Function test(prices As Range)

    test = prices.Rows.Value + prices.Rows.Offset(1, 0).Value

End Function
```

Please advise, thanks v much!

Answer (score 3):

`Value` will only look at a single cell while `Rows` is looking at all rows in your range so your code is trying to add a single cell that thinks it's the entire row and coming back with the computer equivalent of a shoulder shrug.

Try using:

```
Function test(prices As Range) As Double
        test = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(prices.Rows(1).Resize(2))
End Function
```

It will look at the first two rows of whichever range you give it.

This would also work - now looking up as not sure of difference of leaving out the `Worksheetfunction` bit:

```
Function test(prices As Range) As Double
        test = Application.Sum(prices.Rows(1).Resize(2))
End Function
```